# How to force gitlab-ctl to show the installation-type prompt?

Tags: gitlab

When `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` is run for the first time, a menu is shown. I would like to choose another setup, but when the command is run again it immediately starts without showing the menu:

```
root@host:~# gitlab-ctl reconfigure
Starting Chef Client, version 12.12.15
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["gitlab"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - runit (0.14.2)
  - package (0.0.0)
  - gitlab (0.0.1)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Recipe: gitlab::default
  * directory[/etc/gitlab] action create (up to date)
/sbin/init: unrecognized option '--version'
-.mount
```

Running the help subcommand shows the following options:

```
root@host:~# gitlab-ctl help
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl: command (subcommand)
deploy-page
  Put up the deploy page
remove-accounts
  Delete *all* users and groups used by this package
upgrade
  Run migrations after a package upgrade
General Commands:
  cleanse
    Delete *all* gitlab data, and start from scratch.
  help
    Print this help message.
  reconfigure
    Reconfigure the application.
  show-config
```

I have removed the gitlab package, run `cleanse` and `deploy-page up`, but I cannot force the prompt again. How to force gitlab-ctl to show the installation-type prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is related to postfix. Once `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove postfix` and `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` were run the menu appeared.